# How to perform arithmetic manipulations on numbers in Vim?

Tags: vim

If I have a data file with columns of numbers like

```
3.14
0.42
6.66
```

Is there a way from within Vim to manipulate these with operations such as addition, subtraction, and division? For instance, say I want to add 2.1 to each number in a column, how should I go about this?

I can do it by piping to, for instance, an Awk script, but I would like to know if there is a builtin method, and I haven’t found anything in the help files.

Comment: My [NumUtils](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4634) plugin does exactly what you want. You can add, sub, multiply, divide or you can write your own functions to do the calculation. To answer the question you can use :%NumUtilsAdd 2.1

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [CTRL-R](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R) with the expression register `=`.

The following command would add 2.1 to a number on a line:

```
C
<CTRL-R> =
<CTRL-R> "
+2.1
<ENTER>
```

Combine with macro it can yield some interesting results, such as this [example](http://davitenio.wordpress.com/2008/07/01/vim-tip-expression-register-autoincrement-recording/).

Comment: Don't you mean " instead of *? Otherwise the system clipboard gunks it up.

Comment: You are right. With my current config, on Windows, the * register is also mapped to the " register.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with the repeat `.` function? I'd like to have it repeat e.g. multiply this word by 2 `ciw<C-R>=<C-R>"*2<CR><Esc>` but sadly all it does is replace the word by whatever the math worked out to be (which is fair enough as that is what the expression register computed). Seems like I have to come up with some sort of special binding that can do the buffer writing automagically.

Comment: @StevenLu: Make a macro.  Press `q<any letter>`, do whatever you want to record, press `q` to stop recording, then press `q<same letter>` to play it back.

Comment: @Kevin this is actually false, pressing `q<same letter>` will actually start recording a new macro over the macro recorded at that key. To play back you press `@<same letter>`. You can also repeat the last played macro by pressing `@@`.

Comment: Are constants like `pi` available in this mode?

Comment: Ah! The C is very clever! Delete into register and enter insert mode.

Answer (score 7):

Expression registers are great with vim.

Here is a more old fashioned vi way to doing this:
Let us say you have a file containing a bunch of numbers one in each line and you want to add 2.1 to each of the lines.

```
:%s/$/+2.1/<ENTER> - this would append +2.1 to each line.
:1<ENTER>  - Goto the beginning of the file 
!Gbc<ENTER> - invoke the bc command on each line to do the addition.
```

Comment: @Rod.. True you do need a cygwin. I proposed this since she had mentioned awk and hence I assumed that she had access to bc.

Answer (score 5):

A useful feature, which happens to be convenient in this case,
is substitution with an expression (see `:help sub-replace-\=`).
It allows to evaluate an expression on every pattern match of
a substitute command and replace the matched text with the result
of that expression.

For example, to add, say, 2.1 to all values in the third column
of a tab-separated file, one can use the following command.

```
:%s/^\%([^\t]*\t\)\{2}\zs[^\t]*/\=str2float(submatch(0))+2.1/
```